# Trying to import Shapefile to SQL through Command

Tags: shapefile, sql-server

I am a newbie and I'm trying to import a shapefile into SQL Express 2014 via the OGR2OGR tool and I am facing errors.

I installed SQL Express 2014 following this article.

```
http://kb.printaudit.com/display/PA6/SQL+Server+2014+Express+Installation
```

Afterward, I followed the below-mentioned article for Shapefile Import.

```
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/
```

Then I installed QGIS version 2.10. This is the command I entered:

```
ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=JDOE\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySpatial;trusted_connection=yes" C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\ShapeFile\MyShapeFile.shp -nln "Spatial" -progress
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 0 from layer MyShapeFile.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation of layer Ontario_FED_2015 (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not created the database:

```
MSSQL Spatial driver doesn't currently support database creation
```

Try creating your database and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. I created the database and tried again. And now, I am getting a different error message. I have updated my question to reflect the same. Please advise.